# How to perform basic analysis of questionnaire data in SPSS?

Tags: spss

I have no idea about the SPSS and I am having a questionnaire for my dissertation and should analyze it in the SPSS. I downloaded the software and I want to learn the SPSS and how to analyze the questionnaire.
The questionnaire is mixed with Yes/No questions and other staff where are 4 options are available and the sample size is 12.
Can you please instruct me to start with the SPSS and how to analyze the questionnaire.

Comment: Check out the [spss tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/spss/info) for general resources. This question is too broad to be answerable.

Comment: Your data record is structural? First type into a dataset. It means that you can learn some data input instruction by google.

Answer (score 4):

First of all you have to create a data set. You can either add variables to SPSS data table or import it from Excel. You should have first table row with the name of variables. Every next row would be your case. E.g.:

```
Id | Var1 | Var2 | Var3 |
01 | 1    | 0    | 1    |
02 | 01   | 03   | 04   |
...
12 | 16   | 12   | 31   |
```

Second, you have to click "Variable view" and choose the type of variable for every your variable. If you have yes/no variable - you might choose "Nominal". If you have 1 - 4 Variable, it is harder: You have to choose:

1. "Nominal", if the answers are not comperable or measurable.
2. "Ordinal", if answers are comperable, i.e. you can say, that answer
   1 is lower/higher than answer 2 or 3 or 4, but you cannot say
       how much higher/lower.
3. "Scale", If answers are measurable, i.e. you can say, that answer 2 is twice the answer 1, and answer 4 is answer 1 multiplied by 4. This could be the case if you use Likert Scales (Answers: 1 - "Do not agree", 4 - "Completey agree", 2 and 3 - something inbetween).
   N.B.: There are some researchers who would say LIkert Scale is
   rather "ordinal" than "scale".

Third, you have to find the correct method. It depends on you research question. There are a lot of methods and, unfortunately, we need to write a book about what method to use. I think, if you write some words about your hypothesis, research question and data, somebody can answer your question.

I hope it helped.

Best,
Eugene

Answer (score 2):

- Here's some information on [calculating scale scores in SPSS](http://jeromyanglim.blogspot.com.au/2009/10/calculating-scale-scores-for.html)
- Here's some general information about basic steps for [analysing questionnaire data in SPSS](http://jeromyanglim.blogspot.com.au/2009/02/single-group-correlational-study-basic.html).

In general, you might want to get a copy of the SPSS Survival Manual. It is particularly suited to people [getting started with SPSS for thesis analysis](http://www.allenandunwin.com/default.aspx?page=305&book=9781742373928).